# Mobile vertical scrolling issues (sloppy/laggy) when I touch a horizontal scrolling div

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I touch to scroll in the "ok zone", the vertical scrolling is smooth. but when I touch and scroll vertically inside the horizontal boxes It is no more smooth, it weirdly jumps, with laggy stuttering scroll.

[image]

Should I change my design or is there a quick fix?

In order to scroll horizontally I used this for the orange boxes container:

```
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: Can you post fiddle?

Comment: Are you using `scroll` or `touchmove` event listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to the parent with the side scroll.

Comment: Yup. works. So, Should I use scroll-behavior: smooth; every time I create a scrolling feature? Like, why is it not smooth by default?

Comment: @NPLS I generally use it when creating scrollable elements myself. It's not always wanted behaviour. Like on a desktop if you smooth scroll to a place it can take longer, also there are people that can't handle motion that well, so one option is to use it with prefers-reduced-motion.